# how to put different values together in one column using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to put different values together in one column
for example,

| NV | Q | value 1 | value 2 | value 3 | value 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | 1 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 234 | 2 | 0 | 15 | 0 | 0 |
| 234 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 0 |
| 234 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 25 |

Depending on Q, the value 1-4 columns values pulled from different columns are different.

I want to make it like the below table with Q or without Q

| NV | Q | value 1 | value 2 | value 3 | value 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | 1234 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 25 |

values are double

Comment: what if you have multiple values in value 1 or value 2 columns ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
df
.selectExpr(
    "CONCAT_WS('', COLLECT_SET(NV)) as NV",
    "CONCAT_WS('', COLLECT_SET(Q)) as Q",
    "CONCAT_WS('', FILTER(COLLECT_SET(`value 1`), elem -> elem <> 0)) AS `value 1`",
    "CONCAT_WS('', FILTER(COLLECT_SET(`value 2`), elem -> elem <> 0)) AS `value 2`",
    "CONCAT_WS('', FILTER(COLLECT_SET(`value 3`), elem -> elem <> 0)) AS `value 3`",
    "CONCAT_WS('', FILTER(COLLECT_SET(`value 4`), elem -> elem <> 0)) AS `value 4`"
).show(false)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|NV |Q   |value 1|value 2|value 3|value 4|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|234|1234|10     |15     |20     |25     |
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```